# Delivering messages from SNS to SQS in batches

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm sending messages to SNS from where they are redistributed to SQS standard queues. There is a separate SNS subscription for each queue with its own filter policy. The volume of messages is high enough to become a cost issue so I'm looking for ways to minimize it.

For SQS costs, I see three billing items: Receive, Send and DeleteMessage.

I've already applied long polling on the consumer side of SQS and this decreased Receive requests significantly. I think I can apply batching to DeleteMessage in a similar manner.

But I struggle to understand if I can save on Send operations. Is SNS able to send messages to SQS in batches? I didn't find any mention in the documentation. If I send messages to SNS in a batch, would they also be delivered in a batch to SQS? If yes, does it apply if I have message filtering in a subscription?

Comment: I doubt SNS can send in batches. It responds 'immediately' to incoming messages sent to a Topic, so there is no mechanism to make it wait for a while and batch messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PublishBatch API to send batch of messages to SNS, the same will be delivered via SendMessageBatch API of SQS. You can test it by sending messages in batch to SNS and monitoring the SQS API calls via cloudtrail